# Vaadin 7 loader during view initialization

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 application when I first time trying to access my view - Vaadin shows spinner and then hide it. Then I see a blank screen for 2-4 seconds(this is a heavy view) and after that Vaadin shows the application.

How to tell Vaadin to not hide the spinner until the view is completely built ?

**UPDATED**

This is an output information from Vaadin debug window(url with `?debug` parameter):

[image]

Comment: Usually the loading indicator is visible until a longer request is completed, but depending on what's happening, there are a few corner-cases in which it might not appear, such as heavy javascript execution or multi-threaded back-end process. Can you provide more details, perhaps a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I think it will be hard right now due to a big amount of code ..  Also, I have noticed that in FireFox the delay is much more longer than in Google Chrome..

Comment: Are you perhaps sending a lot of objects to the client, for example a table with thousands of records or with many columns?

Comment: I have a few GridStack https://github.com/alump/GridStack components at the screen

Comment: Ok, but what's the heavy operation? What's happening in the backend? What's the output, what does it send to the frontend?

Comment: @Morfic I have added the demo project here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677582/vaadin-7-component-lazy-loading-for-performance-improvement that can reproduce this issue. I'll really appreciate if you could help me to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should possible to show your own spinner first thing in your `UI.init()`, then "postpone" the rest of the lengthy init by wrapping it in an `access()` method (didn't test this). You would need `@Push` for this though.

```
@Push
public class MyUI extends UI {

  public void init() {
    ... // show your spinner here
    access(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            ... // do  your lengthy initialization here...
         }
     });
   }
 }
```

It is possible though that the `access` will kick in rightaway and still blocks the initial response with just the spinner. If that is the case, you should wrap the `access` once more inside a `new Thread()`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for a some reason. After application loading I'm seeing an empty Vaadin window.