# Vaadin 7 component lazy loading for performance improvement

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin 7 application I have a heavy view. Server side works pretty fast - all logic in my init() method takes ~100-150ms but rendering in the browsers takes a lot of time(depends on number of components). Right now it is ~10sec in order to display this view in Google Chrome.

I'm looking for a way in order to optimize performance of this view. I found [LazyLoadWrapper](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/lazyloadwrapper) but it looks a little bit outdated.

Is any similar to this component for Vaadin 7.6 in order to improve user experience and performance of view rendering ?

[image]

**UPDATED**

This is a demo project [Vaadin Demo Project](http://componentwanted.com/uploads/vaadin-ui.zip) that can reproduce this performance issue.

In order to start this application please simple run Maven command:

```
mvn clean install
```

from project folder in order to compile the source and Vaadin theme.

and then run `com.techbook.ui.Application` class (this class contains main method) and the application will be started on Embedded Tomcat 8 and then please access a following url:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/vaadin-ui/#!decisions/123/Name

`com.techbook.ui.view.decision.DecisionView` - is a view with a mentioned performance issue.

Comment: Which components does your view contain? And how many? In my experience, Vaadin is not designed to have a lot of components especially when in several (nested) layouts. Try reduce the number of components/layouts.

Comment: I have added screenshot to my question. As you can see I have a few GridStack with a nested components. I need to handle ~80 elements in the main GridStack but in this case my view loads about ~15-20 sec... Right now I'm thinking about introducing some lazy loading

Comment: You could check what happens if only half of the elements are rendered. Is the time in browser reduced then? I have no idea how lazy loading of components could be implemented (except with the add-on you mentioned).

Comment: Yes, in case of ~10 elements in the main GridStack the rendering time is pretty close to normal

Comment: You may post an issue to the GridStack add-on then. Hopefully, they can help you.

Comment: I have updated my question and provided a demo project that can produce this performance issue. I'll really appreciate any help in order to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Custom Layouts for this "heavy view", probably in combination with a simple htlm template.
Another possibility that the application becomes faster is to replace certain layout combinations. E.g. Instead of a VerticalLayout and HorizontalLayout combination use a GridLayout.
Use the AutoCompleteTextField or SuggestField addon instead of a NativeSelect or ComboBox if the UI guideline allows that.

I hope some of my suggestions may help you,

Florian

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I replaced Vertical/Horizontal layouts with CssLayout but it doesn't help. I can share my source if needed in order to help me to get rid of this performance issue.

Comment: I have added the dome project to my question